# problema con la instalacion de gulp de forma global en Linux

Tags: nodejs, linux, npm, gulp

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo web, con bajos recursos(una computadora muy antigua) y humildemente estoy haciendo un curso en linea y estoy aprendiendo gulp, he seguido las indicaciones de la pagina oficial de gulp en su quickstar (pueden consultar por acá https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start/ ), pero me aparece un error durante la instalación de gulp, estoy haciendo el proyecto en el sistema operativo Zorin-OS de linux, esto es así porque antes estaba haciendo el mismo proyecto en Windows 10 pero mi computadora no lo soporta y quedaba aún más lenta, tanto que no podia terminar el proyecto,  entonces decido mudar el proyecto a Zorin, para continuar con el proyecto, he instalado nodejs y se ha instalado bien y de forma normal, aquí les muestro una imagen para que vean

[image: Prueba de la instalación de nodejs, npm y npx como señala la quickstar]

ahora cuando procedo a instalar gulp de forma global en el equipo ya que lo usare a lo largo del proyecto, me salta un error señalando "deprecated" u obsoleto, aqui lo pueden apreciar:

[image: ERROR de instalación de gulp]

incluso cambie a súper usuario y aun me saltaba el error, todo este error es en la instalación de forma global, pero aquí pueden ver el archivo pachage.json del proyecto para que lo puedan ver:

```js
{
  "name": "festivalmusica_inicio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Aprendiendo Gulp y SASS",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "SASS",
    "Gulp",
    "Web",
    "Design"
  ],
  "author": "Diomar Villarroel",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: La verdad nunca he usado `gulp`, pero ¿no necesitas instalarlo primero y después `gulp cli`? [enlace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp/v/4.0.2) también aquí hay una guía para instalarlo tal vez te funcione con esos pasos [enlace](https://noviello.it/es/como-instalar-gulp-js-en-ubuntu-20-04-lts/)

Comment: incluso creo que debes instalarlo dentro del proyecto